# Qt5Ftp corrupt after build

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

I follow [this](http://ericzwliu.blogspot.com/2015/01/qt-using-qftp-on-qt5.html?showComment=1427446597798) tutorial to build Qt5Ftp lib but it told me that

```
LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file:cannot read at 0x2C0
```

Basically, after i changed < QtFtp/qurlinfo.h > to "qurlinfo.h", i build project to create dll, lib and prl files.

Copy .dll into C:\Qt5.3.2\5.3\msvc2012_opengl\bin

Copy .lib, .prl into C:\Qt5.3.2\5.3\msvc2012_opengl\lib

Copy  C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtNetwork to qftp.h ,qurlinfo.h

Create QFtp in C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtNetwork

And add

```
LIBS += C:/Qt5.3.2/5.3/msvc2012_opengl/bin/Qt5Ftp.dll
```

into .pro file.

Where did i go wrong? And thank for dropping by

Comment: You went wrong by not trying to build it again, after removing the build folder first. I think.

Comment: I build it 2 times, so i need to remove the first build folder?

Comment: Just remove the build folder where the current build would go into, and build again.

Comment: I already try it, no luck either. Can you tell me again what files i have to copy to?